# Java Collections.singletonList(object) C# equivalent

Tags: c#, .net, collections

What would be the C# equivalent to the following:

Java:

```
String data = "dataString";
Collections.singletonList(data);
```

Specifically for the Collections.singleton(object) function. Thanks in advance.

`Collections.singletonList` documentation description:

> Returns an immutable list containing only the specified object. The returned list is serializable.

Comment: `ImmutableList` or `ReadOnlyCollection` I suspect is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

This may solve your purpose.

```
var lst = Enumerable.Repeat(data,1);
```